# Use BackboneJS collections or rather cascaded models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have plan items and want to structure a plan out of a collection of those items. However, it's not as easy as those "book-library-examples" that are commonly used to explain Backbone's collection concept. While each plan item may contain attributes like 'name', 'description', 'usage' and so on, the plan itself is not just a plain collection of items. Basis of the plan is, say, a calendar. And each part of the day can have one or more plan items.

Is a collection still ideal to model such a plan? If so, how? Or should I rather declare a "day" model, that contains plan item objects in a certain structure? What would a good architecture for such an issue look like?

By the way, I can't find those medium level Backbone tutorials. I either come across really simple stuff, that leaves many questions asked or the heavy stuff, that assumes way too much JavaScript experience to be thoroughly followed and understood by me. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, imho you should have some javascript experience if you want to move away from those "intro" examples, in particular if you have such a problem domain as yours. You might one to take a look at [this book](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/), especially towards the end.

Concerning your problem/question, you should rethink your definition of a (backbone) collection. Just think of it as a simple array with syntactic sugar for common tasks for all your elements or as a single point of responsibilty (think of some common event handlers). You can use it, but you mustn't. Generally speaking, grouping models together is imho always nicer because you tend to keep cleaner and more focused models. ;-)

In the end it all comes down to your model. And if you then throw them into a collection or not, is up to you.